# Xcode5.0.2 crashes when I run the project

Tags: xcode, crash

When I build the project, it works fine. However, when I run the project, the Xcode will crash and let me reopen it. Yesterday it was just fine and I did nothing after yesterday's coding.

Comment: Report it: [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Have you tried 5.0.2? I did not encounter this problem with 5.0.1 or 5.0.2. I am using maverick.

Answer (score -1):

I also got this crash today. I searched for it and tried "Do Not Use Auto layout" "Update the Xcode" "Reinstall Xcode".They all didn't work.
I still don't know how this crash happened. But maybe you are able to try this way: Product-Scheme-Edit Scheme-Debugger-Change "LLDB" into "none". Then it works.